# What is the alternative of TRUNC(DATE) in Hive?

Tags: sql, datetime, hive, hiveql, date-arithmetic

I have Oracle SQL query where it has been used `TRUNC(04-Aug-2017 15:35:32)`
What will be parameter in Hive to replace TRUNC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a timestamp, say `ts`, you can use `trunc()`:

```
trunc(ts, 'day')
```

This returns a *timestamp*, with the time portion stripped off - which is similar to what `trunc()` does in Oracle when given one argument only.

On the other hand, you can also convert the timestamp to a date:

```
to_date(ts)
```

This returns a *date* rather than a timestamp: that's a different datatype, that has no time component (Oracle does not have such a datatype: both `date` and `timestamp` store the date *and* time).

Comment: I tried using TO_DATE(04-Aug-2017 15:35:32) which output is 04-Aug-2017. But when I see the rule if TRUNC, it says "TRUNC(date, format) -- The format argument is optional. Its default value is DD that instructs the TRUNC() function to truncate the date to midnight.". Then how can we achieve same goal using hive?

Comment: @DineshMadhup: as you can see, `trunc()` in Hive takes a second argument, which defines the granularity that you want to use to truncate. This is explained in the answer already.

Comment: But we can't use trunc() function in Hive. Right? When can't use trunc(ts, 'day')

Comment: @DineshMadhup: we *can* use `trunc()` in Hive. It takes two arguments - the second argument is mandatory, and it can take various unit, such as `day`, `hour`, `month`, etc. In Oracle, the second argument is optional, and defaults to  `DD`. This is explained in my answer. See also the documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a date/time, you can use the [`to_date()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) function:

```
select to_date(col)
```

Comment: @DineshMadhup . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

As per Oracle docs, The TRUNC (date) function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt. The value returned is always of datatype DATE, even if you specify a different datetime datatype for date. If you omit fmt, then date is truncated to the nearest day.

[image: Below is a sample query:]

Similar is the function of to_date function in Hive.

It returns the date part of a timestamp string (pre-Hive 2.1.0): to_date("1970-01-01 00:00:00") = "1970-01-01".

If what you want is the timestamp(midnight timestamp : 00:00:00) along with the truncated date, you need to use some conversions as shown below:

```
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(<YOU_DATE_COL>), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as timestamp)
```